# What am I missing with this Findstr command?

Tags: command-line, dos, findstr

What am I missing with this Findstr command?

```
X:\Admin>findstr /s/i/c:"permission denied" *.*
FINDSTR: // ignored
FINDSTR: // ignored

X:\Admin>findstr -s-i-c:"permission denied" *.*
FINDSTR: /- ignored
FINDSTR: /- ignored

X:\Admin>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add spaces between the parameters:

```
findstr /s /i /c:"permission denied" *.*
```

Comment: The other option is to combine the options with only one option prefix: `findstr /sic:"permission denied" *` or `findstr -sic:"permission denied" *`

Comment: @dbenham, Such weird syntaxes, do they follow any standards?

Comment: @Pacerier - Hell no! See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) to get a sense of just how chaotic this command can be.

Answer (score 2):

You should leave a space between options

```
 findstr /s /i /c:"permission denied" *.*
```

Comment: The other option is to combine the options with only one option prefix: `findstr /sic:"permission denied" *` or `findstr -sic:"permission denied" *`